# How would I refactor my code using filter javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to join two arrays without having any repeating elements:

```
function union(arr1, arr2) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = arr1.length-1; i >= 0; -- i)
     obj[arr1[i]] = arr1[i];
  for (var i = arr2.length-1; i >= 0; -- i)
     obj[arr2[i]] = arr2[i];
  var res = []
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
      res.push(obj[k]);
  }
  return res;
}
union([1, 3, 5], [3, 6, 9]); //[1, 3, 5, 6, 9]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? The Stack Overflow community is not here to refactor your code for you.

Comment: I'm new to js and wanted to know how to use filter for two arrays? like the syntax, i've only used it for one array

Answer (score 0):

Using the spread operator, `...arr1`, we can combine both arrays into one then by creating a Set we can have an array with only unique values automatically.

```
function union(arr1, arr2){
    const unioned = [...arr1, ...arr2];
    return new Set(unioned);
}

union([1, 3, 5], [3, 6, 9]);
```

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/es6-set-vs-array-what-and-when-efc055655e1a

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out:

```
function union(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.concat(arr2.filter((item) => arr1.indexOf(item) < 0))
}
union([1, 3, 5], [3, 6, 9]); //[1, 3, 5, 6, 9]
```